# Rendering multiple scenes same renderer

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I am attempting to render multiple scenes using the same renderer. I have already referenced other stackoverflow answers to the question, but I am unable to do this successfully.

I load each of my gltf models separately. In my HTML file, they are assigned to the same canvas. When I attempt to render, the first render doesn't appear, and the second one shows a black box!

Conceptually, I want to render two meshes, but I don't want to use two WebGL renderers. My understanding is that the aforementioned method allows me to render one scene, clear it, then render the second--with the first render still being visible in the first scene.

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

```js
// Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // my first gltf file here
    function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );

    },
  
 // Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // my second gltf file here
    function ( gltf ) {

        scene2.add( gltf.scene );

    },
  
  // Canvas
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas name here')
    
    // Scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene()
    const scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
```

```js
// Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
})

renderer.autoClear = false
renderer.clear()
renderer.render(scene, camera)
renderer.clearDepth()
renderer.render(scene2, camera)
```

**Edit:** to be clear, I am trying to replicate the effect shown on this webpage: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multiple#webgl_multiple_elements . Notice how each scene has its own container on a different location on the webpage, but it is using the same renderer. I am not randomizing my geometry.

Comment: The code you have should render everything correctly, but make sure you camera can actually see _either_ model first by rendering them individually. Additionally, why not just put both models in the same scene?

Comment: I am trying to display both models in different locations on the webpage. Frankly, I wasn't sure how to best go about this. I tried to emulate this (although on a much, much smaller scale): https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multiple#webgl_multiple_elements 

Notice how each scene has it's own container--that's what my webpage has.

Comment: Notice on that page there is a single canvas that covers the entire page. It then uses viewports and stencils to render only the part of the canvas relevant to the object being rendered.

Comment: @TheJim01 That makes more sense. I'm not clear on what a viewport is, however. I see in the source code that it is defined in the HTML file. Is this what I retrieve with the document.querySelector in my own code--the "container" where the scene is displayed?

Comment: A more direct question is: how do I assign viewports?

Comment: The code is in the example's HTML file. Look for a call to [`renderer.setViewport`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setViewport).

Comment: I think I understand now. My approach should be to use multiple scenes on different locations of the same canvas. To be clear: By default, is there only one viewport per scene?

Comment: OK I figured it out using scissors test thx

Answer (score 0):

Adding scene2 to the renderer is overwriting scene1. I believe the renderer can only handle one scene.

You can add both GLTFs to the same scene.

```
loader.load('exampleOne.gltf', (gltf) => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});

loader.load('exampleTwo.gltf', (gltf) => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

To refactor the above, you can create one GLTFLoader and call it twice.

```
const onLoad = (gltf: any) => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
}

loader.load('exampleOne.gltf', onLoad);
loader.load('exampleTwo.gltf', onLoad);
```

Comment: Thank you. This rendered both models, but they are now overlapping. Furthermore, I want each to display in its own container on the webpage, like here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multiple#webgl_multiple_elements I have edited my question as I suppose it was ambiguous.